# Outlook with custom identity mark

Tags: office-js

Is it possible to implement a custom email signature mechanism with the new [Add-Ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/outlook/add-ins/) API and **mark an eMail as digitally signed** ?

I was not able to find the documentation about interaction with existing routines, maybe someone can point me to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Outlook add-ins overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) Outlook would not activate add-in for messages protected by Information Rights Management (IRM), in S/MIME format or encrypted in other ways for protection. A digitally signed message is an example since digital signing relies on one of these mechanisms.

There is office dev uservoice request to make the [O365 add-ins available to work with signed messages](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32596816-make-signed-emails-available-for-outlook-plugins) which you can upvote and/or add the comments, describing your business case, if you like.

EDIT:

> My use-case is different / the other way around. I want to mark (visually) that a mail is verified by an add-in, preferred the same way as Outlook would mark S/MIME emails.

Outlook will display the little certificate ribbon in the corner of the message view when message is signed. By clicking on it, certificate verification dialog will be invoked. If message is not actually signed, nothing will appear and you cannot make it appear programmatically. Once again this is not the case for O365 add-on as it doesn't work with signed messages at all.

If you want to display your custom information regarding message (for example: "Message verified by add-on", "Message was archived", etc.) there is [NotificationMessages object](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/NotificationMessages?product=outlook&version=v1.5) which adds notification bar to the message view. You may specify your custom icon as well, to make it look like signing certificate Outlook uses (By the way, I wouldn't recommend it as you would mislead user; users know that this icon used for signed messages and expect message to be signed, which is not).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My use-case is different / the other way around. I want to mark (visually) that a mail is verified by an add-in, preferred the same way as Outlook would mark S/MIME emails. I imagine it is the same problem, right ?

Comment: @Roby I have modified my answer, hopefully this is what you are looking for.